# Comma before "named"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> There should be a file, named `something.txt`.

or

> There should be a file named `something.txt`.

Comment: To the person who downvoted my question - what is wrong with it? I just want to be informed for when I post in the future.

Comment: Probably because it shows no research and is mere proofreading.

Comment: I researched, but found no answers, that's why I asked here. The help center says "Spelling and punctuation" questions are welcomed. I just asked whether it's correct to put a comma or not. I didn't know how to describe the situation, so I just gave an example. Should I include some irrelevant pile of text so it would look like I'm not lazy? I titled the question the same way I typed it in Google so that people with the same problem can find the solution. Isn't that the point of Stack Exchange?

Comment: You don't have to include irrelevant material, and you don't have to include a lot, but you do need to make more of an effort.  That's the rule here at ELU. Take a look around the site and try to find some well-received questions.  I think that's a good way to start to get the hang of writing ELU questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the question you need to ask before placing a comma is whether the information being set off is necessary or not.  If it is, then the clause is restrictive, meaning it doesn't need (or usually allow) a comma.  If the information is not necessary, than it's a non-restrictive clause and you should use a comma.

Applying that principle to this particular example, you need to decide whether the reader would reasonably expect that there is already some file in the location being described.  If there was no file there before, than the name of the file that is there now is extraneous, so it can be set off with a comma.

> "The installation procedure will create a directory called /opt/comma.  Inside there should be a file, called commarules.txt."

It is the only file at this location, so its name is irrelevant to the overall meaning of the sentence (although it might be interesting to the reader).  On the other hand, if there were or could already be files in that location, then the reader really needs to know what the file is called before they can say whether it was created correctly.

> "The installer will also create a shortcut for starting the program.  Check your desktop for a file called comma-runner.exe."